# How can I get Fan Page Additional Contact Info (e.g. Twitter, Instagram) by using Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can use my app_token to call the Graph API Explorer to get the basic information of the Fan Page email, website etc...
Just using `/v2.6/20531316728?fields=emails,website,name`

But how can I get the Fan Page Additional Contact Info (e.g. Twitter, Instagram, WeChat, LINE, YouTube, etc...) using app_token?

[image]

Comment: +1 Nothing listed on [Page Graph API Reference v2.12](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/);  No `contact info` or `other accounts` endpoints or fields.  I wonder if/doubt they'll ever open this up... becoming more a walled garden daily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further research after my comment turns up the following...

While not intuitive through the docs, this is available via the [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/) for Pages.  The field you are looking for is `screennames`.

[https://graph.facebook.com/nasa?fields=screennames&access_token=*TOKEN*](https://graph.facebook.com/nasa?fields=screennames&access_token=_TOKEN_)

Example Response

```
{
   "screennames": {
      "data": [
         {
            "service_name": "Twitter",
            "value": "nasa"
         },
         {
            "service_name": "Instagram",
            "value": "nasa"
         },
         {
            "service_name": "Snapchat",
            "value": "nasa"
         },
         {
            "service_name": "YouTube",
            "value": "nasa"
         }
      ]
   },
   "id": "54971236771"
}
```

Note that it returns the free text that people type in the input type on the Facebook Page edit screen.  Sometimes you'll see just the social media name, other times you might see a full or partial url.

Comment: Yeah! Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem @NewHand.  As of today, I don't think it is widely adopted.  As more page owners come back and edit their profiles, it will become so.

Comment: It seems that starting from v3 APIs the `screennames` attribute is no longer available. Is there a way to retrieve this information using the current version?